# How to call the random function

Tags: python, function, random

I have a code which has functions, which should be called randomly. However, when I am running the code below:

```py
def print1():
    print(1)
def print2():
    print(2)
def print3():
    print(3)
l=(print1(), print2(), print3())
x=random.choice(l)
x()
```

It doesn't work properly. It is outputting everything (1, 2, 3)
and raises an exception:

> ''NoneType' object is not callable'

How to fix that?

Comment: `l = [print1, print2, print3]`. You want the list (or tuple, if you prefer) to contain function objects, not what the functions return, which is `None`.

Comment: Expounding on the comment above - calling `print1(), print2(), ...` like you're doing now  executes the functions and they all implicitly `return None`, so `l` is a tuple that looks like `(None, None, None)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def print1():
    print(1)
def print2():
    print(2)
def print3():
    print(3)
l=(print1, print2, print3)
x=random.choice(l)
x()
```

placing the functions without the brackets place the **function** inside the list. Writing the function with the brackets **calls the function**.

Btw u need not store the function into a variable, just do `random.choice(l)()`